# Unity's ResolutionFailedException

Tags: unity-container

I have an old Asp.Net web application using Unity for dependency injection. 
Today I updated the Unity using NuGet to the latest version. On trying to run the application, I am getting an exception:

Unity.Exceptions.ResolutionFailedException: 'Resolution of the dependency failed, type = 'SOME.Services.ISomeService', name = '(none)'.
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The property converter on type DAL.Repositories.SomeRepository is not settable.

The exception happened on line

```
_someService = container.Resolve<ISomeService>();
```

I am very new to Unity. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newer versions of Unity have breaking changes.
You may want to stick with the older versions of the DLL until you refactor the changes.

> v4.0.1 Version 4.x is dead. Loss of original signing certificate made
>   it impossible to release anything compatible with v4.0.1 release. To
>   give original developers a credit only about 60 issues were found
>   during two years in production. To move on and enable further
>   development version v5 has been created.
>
> v5.x Version 5.x is created as replacement for v4.0.1. Assemblies and
>   namespaces are renamed and refactored but otherwise it is compatible
>   with the original. v5.0.0 release fixes most of the issues found in
>   v4.0.1 and implements several optimizations but the accent was on
>   compatibility and if optimization would break API it was omitted. Once
>   stabilized, this version will enter LTS status and will be patched and
>   fixed for the next few years. There will be no significant development
>   in this line.

Check their road map [here](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated from 2.1.505.2 to 5.8.5.

I am not clear on how I can approach to fixing this particular exception.

Comment: Return back to the old version (via Nuget) and things should work or factor you code\configurations to support version 5.8.5.

Comment: Could you please give me some more details on what should be done to fix it?